# How to get Json object name in json response

Tags: json

I have the following JSON format:

```
Object {person: Array[10]}
```

I want to get the name called `person`.

I don't want to get the inner content just I want the name called `person`
to store it in a variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It would be clearer if you used correct terminology: `person` here is a "key".

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you can do this like this, assuming your object is stored in a variable named *obj*:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var person = keys[0];
```

Or another approach:

```
for ( prop in obj ) {
   // prop is the key name.
}
```